# Download de arquivo encerrando sessão no PHP

Tags: php, apache, download

Tenho um sistema de download de arquivos em PHP com login e expiração de sessão em 30 minutos, no início imaginei que fosse algum erro de lógica, porém o usuário do sistema somente é deslogado inesperadamente quando realiza o download de diversos arquivos num curto espaço de tempo. Já se usuário realizar o download de forma cadenciada, um arquivo após outro o mesmo problema não ocorre. Realizando testes percebi que o mesmo somente ocorre quando são arquivos de tamanhos maiores (acima de 40MB).

download.php

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$novoNome.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivoLocal));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Connection: close');  

readfile($arquivoLocal);
exit;
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.close();
</script>
```

Já realizei algumas alterações abaixo:

```
Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
Max_input_time  - 1000
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800
Post_max_size - 2000 M
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527811/how-to-download-large-files-through-php-script

Alguém já passou por esse problema? Conhece alguma configuração para resolver esse problema ou alguma solução para esse problema?

OBS: tenho acesso ao servidor e posso realizar alterações no apache e no php.ini