# Função readfile derrubando sessão PHP

Tags: php

Estive com um problema com downlod de arquivo, onde a sessão era encerrada quando ocorria diversos download num curto espaço de tempo (menos de 1 segundo) e o mesmo não ocorria quando o download era realizado de forma mais lenta. ([Essa questão pode ser acompanhada aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156819/download-de-arquivo-encerrando-sess%C3%A3o-no-php)).

arquivo de download.php

```
<?php
ini_get('safe_mode');
include_once './conf.php'; 
include_once 'class/Conexao.class.php'; 
include_once 'class/Login.class.php'; 

ob_start();
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';

session_start();       
session_regenerate_id();  

//verifica o usuario logado
$log = new Login();

if(!$log->loginCheck() || $log->expired_session()) :
    $site = BASE;
    header("Location:$site");
endif;

if(!isset($_GET['id'])){   header("location: ../erro/5/");}
$id= trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
$arq_id = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$sql = 'SELECT arq_nome, arq_desc FROM arquivo WHERE arq_id = ? LIMIT 1';
$conn = new Conexao();

if($stm = $conn->prepare($sql)):
    $stm->bind_param('i', $arq_id);
    $arq_id = $arq_id;
    $stm->execute();
    $stm->bind_result($arq_nome, $arq_desc);
    $stm->store_result();
    $stm->fetch();
    $dados = array();

    if($stm->num_rows() != 1):
        header("location: ../erro/5/");
    endif;
else:
    echo 'Erro ao selecionar arquivo';
endif;

// Arqui você faz as validações e/ou pega os dados do banco de dados

@set_time_limit(0);

$aquivoNome = $arq_nome; // nome do arquivo que será enviado p/ download
$arquivoLocal = '../../arquivos/XPtCu6bNvxOYBDYilkGL/'. $aquivoNome;

// Verifica se o arquivo não existe
if (!file_exists($arquivoLocal)) {
    // Exiba uma mensagem de erro caso ele não exista
    echo 'nao existe arquivo';
    exit;
}

// Definimos o novo nome do arquivo
$novoNome = $arq_desc;

// Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$novoNome.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivoLocal));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');

// Envia o arquivo para o cliente
//readfile($arquivoLocal);
header('Connection: close');  
exit;
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.close();
</script>
```

php.ini

```
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING
magic_quotes_gpc = On
memory_limit = 128M
output_buffering = 4096
post_max_size = 128M
safe_mode = On
safe_mode_exec_dir = /usr/local/www/apache22/batch
safe_mode_gid = On
upload_max_filesize = 128M
include_path = ".:/usr/local/share/phpmailer"
```

Após o ocorrido a sessão era excluída, conforme log abaixo (sessiontime é a minha sessão):

```
[Thu Oct 06 10:14:39.915176 2016] [:error] [pid 3263] [client 10.0.0.2:52344] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sessiontime in /var/www/html/intranet_academica/adm/index.php on line 106, referer: http://10.0.0.1/intranet_academica/adm/home/6/
```

> OBS: Eu havia comentado a linha que verifica a sessão do usuário e o log acima ocorreu quando tentei acessar uma página que a verificação de login estava ativa.

Após diversos testes acabei chegando á conclusão que essa queda de sessão ocorre quando tento fazer o download de um arquivo sem que um download anterior (algo em torno de 57MB) tenha terminado.

A minha solução foi comentar a linha `readfile` e o problema não ocorreu mais, porém o arquivo ficou em branco.
Alguém conhece qual a restrição em relação a essa função do PHP ligada a destruição da sessão?

Comment: Procurou se reportaram isso como BUG? Coloque as partes principais do código pra facilitar.

Comment: adicionei o meu arquivo de download.php, caso seja necessário poderia postar os arquivos necessários.

Comment: Não procurei se reportaram como BUG, na verdade nem sei como procura-la.

Comment: Chegou a consultar os arquivos de log para verificar possíveis explicações? Os output de log do interpretador PHP estão ativos?

Comment: Sim, a única coisa que encontrei foi que a sessão não existia mais. Até coloquei o log na pergunta acima

Comment: Você está regenerando id: `session_regenerate_id()`, a cada upload, isso faz a sessão cair mesmo, pois você está substituindo a sessão atual por uma nova... Se você quer regenerar a id, faça isso após a conclusão, não durante o processo.

Comment: @IvanFerrer agora que você citou isso estou bem certo que seja esse o problema. E isso responde o motivo do download somente realizar logoff quando um download era realizado antes de outro download terminar o que faz gerar um novo id (`session_regenerate_id()`), o que causa um logoff no primeiro download. Vou continuar os testes e ti darei um retorno

Comment: @IvairFerrer, acredito de a sua solução tenha resolvido o meu problema (até o momento não tive problemas). Se possível favor postar como resposta para aceita-la

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar uma estratégia diferente para ler o arquivo?

```
$fp = fopen("{$file}", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Talvez resolva alguma limitação referente a sobrecarga de caracteres que o readfile tente gerar.

Comment: Uma outra opção seria você gerar o arquivo e um token de autorização em um arquivo, depois redirecionar para a página de download com o token na url e validar se o token ainda é válido não deixando que sessão e arquivo se misturem no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, legal. Caso não obtenha sucesso com a dica acima do @IvairFerrer irei tentar essa opção.